# returning complete page HTML instead of string output in JSON response

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, webmethod

I am trying to achieve a simplest task through ajax using web method  . My web method as follow

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string GetDate()
    {
        return string.Format("says {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString("r"));
    }
```

and ajax code as follow

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#Result").click(function() {
                alert('Result Clicked');

                $.ajax(
               {
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "test1.aspx/GetDate",
                   data : "{}",
                   contentType: "application/json",
                   dataType: "json text",
                   success: function(rsp) {

                       alert('success');
                       alert(rsp);
                       alert(rsp.d);

                       $('#Result').append(rsp.d);


                   },
                   error: function(rsp) {
                       alert(rsp.status + " " + rsp.statusText + "</br>" + rsp.responseText);
                       console.log(rsp);
                       console.log(rsp.responseText);

                   }
               });
            });

        });
```

but status says OK and 200 status code, but instead of simple string in `rsp.d` its shows complete HTML of that page self.

Comment: Did you try with `data: null` or `dataType: text` ? Does your web.config contain entry for `System.Web.Extensions` under <httpHandlers> and <httpModules> ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Can Try this Code May be it is Help Full.

```
$("#Result").click(function () {
                alert('Result Clicked');
                $.ajax(
                    {
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "Default.aspx/GetDate",
                   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                   dataType: "json",
                   success: function (rsp) {
                       alert('success');
                       alert(rsp);
                       alert(rsp.d);
                       $('#Result').append(rsp.d);
                   },
                   error: function (rsp) {
                       alert(rsp.status + " " + rsp.statusText + "</br>" + rsp.responseText);
                   }
               });
            });
```

Comment: contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json", Please Read about Jquery ajax From http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I tired this also same result

Comment: Give me your email Id I will send you Demo application

Comment: Please Check your mail i sent you on rahularyansharma@gmail.com